# Switching Firebase Auth from Android SDK to Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Currently I have an android app that uses the Firebase Auth for user Authentication. I would like to move the authentication part to the Admin Sdk server, such that The android app makes an http request to the server and the server does the authentication. Unfortunately the the Admin SDK for Java does not have the signInWithEmailAndPassword method. Is there a way to go about this or do I have to include the android sdk on the server also?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a supported situation with Firebase Authentication.  The client app must authenticate itself using the client SDK so that it can manage the ID token that lets the other SDKs work with respect to the security rules defined for those products (Realtime Database, Firestore, Storage).

You could [call the Authentication APIs directly](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/auth-without-play-services) from the client, but it's far better to just let the client SDK do all that work for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  I later found a way to do so using the Firebase Auth REST api  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/.

Comment: Do you know if there are any drawbacks to using this method?

Comment: That's what my link was illustrating - how to call the REST APIs.  Never used them myself.